# how to attach two images to mfmailcomposer view controller in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, nsdata, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

How to add web view data and image view data to Mfmailcomposer view controller in ios.
for sending mail to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
for (UIImage *yourImage in YourImageArray )
{
            NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 0.5);
            [mfMailComposer addAttachmentData:imgData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:[NSString  
            stringWithFormat:@"a.jpg"]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can Firest Create a imageFull path Array what you want attech with Email and do like bellow:-

```
- (IBAction)sendemail
{

    Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
    if (mailClass != nil)
    {
        // We must always check whether the current device is configured for sending emails
        if ([mailClass canSendMail])
        {


            MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [picker setSubject:@"Hello"];
            //NSString *result = txtFiled.text;
            for(NSString *dicsss in buttonss) // Hear buttonss its a ImagePathfull array
            {
                UIImage *imgvith = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[buttonss stringByAppendingPathComponent:dicsss]];
                NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgvith);
                [picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"yourImagename"];

            }


            NSString *emailBody = @"Hi";
            [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
            [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
            [picker release];
        }


}
```

Working Code screenShot look like:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is

```
[mailCompose setMessageBody: msg isHTML: YES];
```

where msg have value:

```
<body>
<img src='http://your_site/image1.jpg'>
<img src='http://your_site/image2.jpg'>
<br/>

<font face='Arial' size='2'>
  Message Text<br/>

  <br/>
</font>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add more than one Image in your mail composer instanse. But make sure file name is is different. Check it here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008200-CH1-SW2.